# CodeIgniter foreach loop. How to refer to object "key"

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, key, stdclass

I have a black out since 1 hour ago.
I working in CI and I have following array:

```
   Array
   (
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 58
            [idAby] => 57
            [utilizator] => gigel@gigel.com
            [parola] => ########
            [group] => 3
            [nume] => Georgescu
            [confirm] => 1
        )

   )
```

In viewer, I'm simply loop array as follow :

```
 <?php foreach($arr as $key=>$value):?>
 <span id="<?=$value->id?>"><?= $value->nume ?></span>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

But my question is if there is a simply way to return stdClass Object key ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. In that example, what you need to get is `[0]`? or you need a list of the object properties?

Comment: Your question is not clear? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Hisamu I want to get [id] or [nume]. But no problem. I find other way to do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_object_vars()` is what you need. Combine with `array_keys()` and you have an array with all the properties.

http://en.php.net/get_object_vars

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you would like to know the properties of an object. If that is correct, I would suggest looking at [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) in the php.net manual.

According to the manual:

> Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static
>   properties for the specified object in scope.

Example:

```
<?php 
$properties = get_object_vars($value);
```